# cell.contentView.viewWithTag gives nil value while loading data in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewwithtag

I am looking to captured image tap event on the first record of `UITableView`, when user taps I `cell.imageAvtar` I just want to capture that event.

This is the code I am using

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("details", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AccountCell
                if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: "no_image_available.jpg")
    }
return cell
}
```

But `(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101)` is returning as `nil`.I have tried `(cell.contentView.viewWithTag(100)` tried (cell. imageAvtar.viewWithTag(101) as well.

Comment: Since the cell is custom anyway why do you use tags rather than IBOutlets ?

Comment: What @vadian said. Tags are useless and fragile. Use outlets or properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `IBOutlets` as vadian and jrturton advised.

This is the working code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("details", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AccountCell
                if (indexPath.row == 0) {  let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
                cell.imageAvtar.userInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.imageAvtar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    }
     func imageTapped(img: AnyObject)
        {
                 print("event captured")
                //your logic comes here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

check your imageView's tag in interface builder or storyboard if it is 0 make it 101 and retry..

you can also check

```
for subView in cell.contentView.subView {
    print("subView tag --> \(subView.tag)!")
}
```

try this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`cell.viewWithTag(101)` or `self.view.viewWithTag(101)` if tag is unique(i.e. if you are not using this tag at other place).

Second thing you have to add `gesture recognizer` to capture event on it. How you come to know that it's returning nil ? It may not return nil. You are making another mistake. Make sure that `no_image_available.jpg` is properly available in project!

Another thing is make sure that you have set tag properly.

Comment: `no_image_available.jpg  ` is available. I have tried
`if (cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) ) != nil{
                    print("image found")
                }else{
                    print("somethign went wrong")
                }`

Also, neither `cell.viewWithTag(101)` nor `self.view.viewWithTag(101)` helped